# python list insertion

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

Say you have a list of tuples such as:

```
list1 = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)]
```

and you want to add the tuple (0, 1, 0) to the list it should be in the order then:

```
list1 = [(0, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)]
```

and say you also want to add the tuple (0,1,1) to the list it should be in the order then:

```
list1 = [(0, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)]
```

and say you also want to add the tuple (3,1,0) to the list it should be in the order then:

```
list1 = [(0, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (3, 1, 0)]
```

I want to try and come up with a function which takes three parameters based on the values within the tuple (def (value1, value2, value3):...) and using that it can find the index value and insert the tuple in the list in the correct order. Finding it quite difficult and help would be appreciated

Comment: "takes three parameters": what are the three parameters?  Aren't there just the list and whatever you're inserting into it?  (This sounds a lot like what `bisect.insort_left` does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things simple just append the new values and sort the list:

```
a = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)]

def add_to_list(item1, item2, item3, the_list):
    the_list.append((item1, item2, item3))
    return sorted(the_list)    

print(add_to_list(0, 1, 0, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

To insert a single tuple if `list1` is sorted:

```
import bisect

bisect.insort(list1, (0, 1, 0))
```

To merge two sorted list:

```
import heapq

tuples = [(0,1,0), (0,1,1), (3,1,1)]
list1 = list(heapq.merge(list1, tuples))
```

Or for small lists (`len(L) < 1000000`):

```
list1.extend(tuples)
list1.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def fun(value1, value2, value3):
        tup = (value1, value2, value3)
        list1.append(tup)
        list1.sort()
        return(list1)

>>> list1 = [(0, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)] 
>>> fun(0,1,1)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: sorry for almost similar answer, concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing function:

```
a = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)]
a = sorted(a+[(0,1,1)])
```

Using function (t is tuple):

```
f = lambda a,t: sorted(a+[t])
a = f(a, (1, 1, 0))
```